# Android Studio - Updating text fields with new incoming data

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have just started learning Android Studio and have been experimenting with Handlers to allow me to 'send' data around my program. I have a Handler routine in  my Main Activity which receives data. My problem is how do update a text control / field on the main activity screen to show this data which changes every two seconds?
If I get a reference to the control and then try to update the text field within the handler routine the program stops and exits with an error.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks
John

my code:

```
public Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> receiveData = new ArrayList<>();
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        receiveData =bundle.getIntegerArrayList("channels");
        System.out.println("array data = " + receiveData);

        EditText dataText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data); // causes error !
        dataText.setText(String.valueOf(receiveData));

    }
```

Comment: Think you should run on UI thread your piece of code (updating the UI).
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Update UI elements
    }
});

Comment: declare this outside handler: 

EditText dataText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);

Answer (score 1):

Android prevents any kind of interaction with UI elements outside the main thread, so the quickest way to solve your issue is running the UI updating code in the UI thread as follows:

```
public Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> receiveData = new ArrayList<>();
        Bundle bundle = msg.getData();
        receiveData = bundle.getIntegerArrayList("channels");
        System.out.println("array data = " + receiveData);

        runOnUiThread() { new Runnable() {
               EditText dataText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);
               dataText.setText(String.valueOf(receiveData));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: an alternative (and probably) better approach is using the system-provided [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class whose `onProgressUpdate` method is called on the main `Thread` to allow `View` updates

Comment: @Droidman I agree, didn't mention it as I think OP wanted something faster, but AsyncTask is preferred over handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have  tried the above example code, but unfortunately it generates  a few errors.

Comment: The code 'runOnUiThread() {' produces the error ' runOnUIthread (Runnable) in Activity can not be applied to {} '.  I will have look at examples on this site on how to use Async Task as suggested by yourself and @Droidman

Comment: To use Handler or Async Task ....
Reading up of Async Task, I get the impression this is recommended to be used for short durations of a few seconds. My data is coming from an established  bluetooth link at a rate of once a second which is present all the time the app is running.

Comment: My Handler Routine:....  Putting in the suggested runOnUiThread()  approach still didn't work. Looking at the debug window the 'dataText'  parameter was returning 'null' which I guess means undefined.  I got the code to run without crashing by placing 'dataText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.data);' in the 'onCreate' fuction but the change which made it work  was delaring ' TextView  dataText; ' as static ! Not quite sure why making it static works.The programme now  runs ok with or without  the 'runOnUiThread()' code present.

Answer (score 0):

Handlers may make your code over-complicated and difficult to read and maintain. I suggest to use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). Basically you register your activity/fragment to receive updates for a specific event, and when you receive it you update the UI.
Have a look at the EventBus, it's super easy to use and very good in doing what you are trying to do "***'send' data around my program"*** :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Tried using the Otto EventBus which seem to work well.... but hit the same problem as the Handler routine when trying to update screen text fields dynamically. Now I managed to overcome this issue I will see how the EventBus structure works with different screens. I assume that with Handlers you have to create a different handler each time you want to send data to a different part of the programme ?

Comment: I am not sure if you are using it correctly. The beauty of EventBus is that you don't need handlers. If you need to update a fragment or a view, make the fragment or the the view itself to register for event and implement in them the method to update the UI.

Comment: Sorry I think you misunderstood my comment,  I was comparing the complexity of creating lots of handlers to the more simple approach using EventBus . Create / initialise Event Bus once and then call/use anywhere within your programme !

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your `Handler` like below code:-

```
Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
//Your code here

}
});
```

You need to use `Handler.Callback` when constructing `Handler`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This did not work,  probably for the reasons mentioned above regarding thread issues.

Answer (score 0):

firstly add this line for definition loophandler ,

```
private Handler loophandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

And add this code for loop every 3 second .

```
final Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {




                                        loophandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void run() {
                                               // insert your code 
                                            }

                                        }, 0);



                                }



                    }, 0, 3000);
```

- You can use  `timer.cancel();`  To close the timer and close loop
- You can add the code you want to repetition in (public void run)

Comment: Please format your code properly, and provide a proper explanation about how your solution solves the problem.